# Netplan configuration problems in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, netplan

I would like to know how could I change interface names in Ubuntu 20.04. I have configured the `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file as follow:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
        nf0:
                  match:
                          macaddress: 02:53:55:4d:45:00
                  macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00
                  addresses:
                        - 192.168.1.0/24
                  optional: true
                  set-name: nf0
        nf1:
                  match:
                          macaddress: 02:53:55:4d:45:01
                  macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:01
                  addresses:
                        - 192.168.1.1/24
                  optional: true
                  set-name: nf1
        nf2:
                  match:
                          macaddress: 02:53:55:4d:45:02
                  macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:02
                  addresses:
                        - 192.168.1.2/24
                  optional: true
                  set-name: nf2
        nf3:
                  match:
                          macaddress: 02:53:55:4d:45:03
                  macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:03
                  addresses:
                        - 192.168.1.3/24
                  optional: true
                  set-name: nf3
```

As far as I know, I have to define each interface inside the `ethernets:` node. My intention is to find the interface by matching the MAC address (using the `match` option) and set the name (using `set-name:`), a new MAC address (using `macaddress:`) and an IP address (using `addresses:`). Every interface is configured as expected except one of them (some times nf3 does not take the configuration and other times nf2 does not take it). There has to be something wrong with the configuration above, but I cannot see it. I have also read the [reference](https://netplan.io/reference/), but I may have misread it or I have missed something. I would appreciate some insights in the problem I present. Following I put the `ifconfig` output so you can see how `nf2` is called `enp1s0` and it does not take on the IP I indicated in the configuration file.

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 420  bytes 136080 (136.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 70:8b:cd:9e:d7:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38759  bytes 32961673 (32.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 19  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27510  bytes 3688242 (3.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3424  bytes 356738 (356.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3424  bytes 356738 (356.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nf0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:53:55:4d:45:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nf1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 688  bytes 118186 (118.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nf3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 2471 (2.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 5 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Also, if it helps, here is the `uname -a` output:

```
Linux main 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you for your comments and help.

Edit (in response to heynnema's comment): enp5s0 is from the motherboard, but enp1s0, nf0, nf1, nf3 are from a [NetFPGA-SUME](https://netfpga.org/site/#/systems/1netfpga-sume/details/) programmed with a synthesized NIC and connected via PCIe. I have not used neither IP 192.168.0.0 nor IP 192.168.0.1 (nonetheless I changed IPs to 192.168.1.150-192.168.1.153 and nothing changed).

I need to change MAC addresses because I am building a prototype where I have two hosts with one NetFPGA-SUME connected to each one (so each host has got 4 ethernet ports: nf0, nf1, nf2 and nf3). I plan to communicate each host via a switch (implemented in a third NetFPGA-SUME board). I have to change the MAC address because port nf0 in host A has the same MAC address than nf0 in host B. Therefore, I want to distinguish them. Also, I think there would be problems when filling up the switch TCAM.

I want to use `set-name` for readability, so I can distinguish clearly between interfaces. I don't want to confuse one of the nfX ports with the motherboard ethernet port.

Regarding the DNS question, I don't really want to have any connection to the Internet through those ports (the one givin internet connection is enp5s0), so I don't thing they would be necessary. I think that I could also remove the IPs because the switch only works on the 2nd layer, but I'm just curious on why one of the interfaces does not take the IP properly.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 70:8b:cd:9e:d7:6b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe804000-fe804fff memory:fe800000-fe803fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: nf1
       serial: 00:00:00:00:00:01
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=NetFPGA SUME (RIFFA DMA) driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic ip=192.168.1.151 multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: nf2
       serial: 00:00:00:00:00:02
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=NetFPGA SUME (RIFFA DMA) driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic ip=192.168.1.152 multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       serial: 00:00:00:00:00:03
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=NetFPGA SUME (RIFFA DMA) driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic multicast=yes
```

Output of `grep GRUB /etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: What happens if you run `netplan apply` after boot?  A quick google shows some bug reports with 18.04 that might be related. E.g.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1768827
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1770082

Comment: Nothing happens. When rebooting though, `nf3` is misconfigured instead of `nf2` as I indicated in the post. Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: Are the enp ethernet ports on the motherboard, and the nf ethernet ports on a PCI card? You can't use addresses 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.1. Why change the MAC addresses? Why use set-name? Where are the DNS's? Indentation is all wrong. Show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Also `grep GRUB /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @heynnema I answered your questions and showed the outputs of the commands by editing the original post, so it can be seen more easily. Regarding indentation, I don't see why its wrong. I have had indentation problems before, but they were detected when generating the backend configuration.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I tried to change the MAC address of _nf0_ to a different one and when I did it, everything was solved (both the names of the interfaces and the issue of _nf0_ not taking the configuration). I did not post an answer because I couldn't explain thoroughly why the problem was solved.

Comment: @anmomu Interesting. Must be because `macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00` has an invalid MAC. I updated my answer to reflect your fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

From https://github.com/NetFPGA/NetFPGA-SUME-public/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide...

**Host Motherboard**

The NetFPGA-SUME board works both standalone and inside a host. If you intend to use the NetFPGA-SUME board in a host, you need to make sure that the motherboard supports PCI Express Gen3 x8 configuration. It is recommended to have an up-to-date firmware on your motherboard. For some motherboards, you may need to set the PCI Express configuration to Gen3 in the BIOS configuration manually.

- Verify current BIOS with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Update as necessary.
- Verify BIOS setting for Gen3.

**YAML**

Your .yaml should look something more like this skeleton... and indentation should be 2 spaces, no tabs...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      # populate as required
    nf0:
      # populate as required
    nf1:
      # populate as required
    enp1s0:
      # populate as required
    nf3:
      # populate as required
```

**GRUB**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Minor nit... you only need "ipv6.disable=1" once.

**Update #1:**

`macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00` for nf0 in the original .yaml file is not valid. Used a different MAC and it's all working now.